# Upload a pepk file created from exist jks

Tags: google-play, android-app-signing

My app in Google Play is distribute as signed-by-myself APK and I didn't join App Signing before.

Since I want to create an app bundle internal test, Google team demand me to join App Signing. So I'd like to upload my jks to Google Play Console.

I create a pepk under the direction of **Setup -> App Signing -> App integrity -> Use existing app signing key from Java KeyStore** .

- If I upload this pepk, would Google Play change the signing info of my published APK?
- Can I upload a signed-by-myself APK for app upgrade?
- The pepk is created from the jks that sign my signed-by-myself APK, can user upgrade app in GP properly?

I email the google team. They said the pepk I uploaded would affect all the apk/aab in Google Play and that confuse me.